# Matching columns in R

Tags: r, match

I have several years of data with unique reference codes, what I'm looking to do is track how the reference codes appear in the data over time, does anyone have a method to do this? I'll give an example of what I'm looking for. 
This might be how the data looks:

| 2005 | 2006 | 2007 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 92837503 | 75482342 | 54654656 |
| 34923478 | 13049483 | 98769879 |
| ..... | ..... | ..... |
| 09340823 | 2304923 | 0988775 |

and what I'm looking to do is match the unique references across the years and have blanks where they might not appear:

| 2005 | 2006 | 2007 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 92837503 | 92837503 | 92837503 |
| 34923478 | na | 34923478 |
| ..... | ..... | ..... |
| 09340823 | na | na |
| na | 2304923 | na |

Comment: Your example is unclear. Why does `928...` repeat across all 3 years of the output, but not `349...`?

Comment: What is your input data structure? Are they all in one data frame? Or separate data frame/vectors for each year? This seems like a fairly simple `full_join` operation, but hard to know without understanding your input. Your example is strange because your input has 2005 and 2006 and your output has 2007 too, seemingly out of nowhere...

Comment: Please share a little but of sample input reproducibly, either with R code to create the object or with `dput()` (which creates R code to create an object, e.g., `dput(your_data[1:5, ])` for the first 5 rows of a data frame named `your_data`).

Comment: @GregorThomas at the moment they're in seperate data frames, just with the one year of data and the single column

Comment: Great. Please share a few rows of 3 data frames reproducibly. `dput(your_2005_data[1:5, , drop = FALSE])`, `dput(your_2006_data[1:5, , drop = FALSE])`, `dput(your_2007_data[1:5, , drop = FALSE])`. Then we can test code out to solve your problem. We'll probably want to gather all of the relevant data frames in a `list`, so if there is a pattern in how they are named that would be good to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**code**

```
library(data.table)

Reduce(f = function(x, y) merge(x, y, by = c("i"), all = T), lapply(list(df1, df2, df3), function(x) setDT(x)[, i := x[, 1L]]))
```

**sample data**

```
df1 <- data.frame(`2005` = c(1,3,6,7,12))
df2 <- data.frame(`2006` = c(12,2,4,7,10))
df3 <- data.frame(`2007` = c(4,100))
```

**results**

```
#      i X2005 X2006 X2007
# 1:   1     1    NA    NA
# 2:   2    NA     2    NA
# 3:   3     3    NA    NA
# 4:   4    NA     4     4
# 5:   6     6    NA    NA
# 6:   7     7     7    NA
# 7:  10    NA    10    NA
# 8:  12    12    12    NA
# 9: 100    NA    NA   100
```

**detailed explanation**

Here the one liner break down in three lines (steps)

You mention you have your data.frames stored seperately, so we add them to a list.

```
dfs <- list(df1, df2, df3)
```

Then we apply over each of your tables in the list and create a universal column we can merge on later on, the column will be called "i". `setDT` makes the `data.frame`s a `data.table` and `i := x[x, 1L]` makes sure the i value will be your value.

```
dfs <- lapply(dfs, function(x) setDT(x)[, i := x[, 1L]])
```

Then we can use the base `Reduce` function to merge the list of tables on the universal column i. Reduce function has two values, x is the previous (merge) result and y the new value (next table to merge).

```
Reduce(f = function(x, y) merge(x, y, by = c("i"), all = T), dfs)
```

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the easiest/quickest way, but my method would be to pivot/unpivot

```
library(tidyverse)

data %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = colnames(data), #this assumes that only your years are the columns in the data.
               names_to = "year",
               values_to = "code") %>%
  mutate(id_code = code) %>% #This will line up the codes on the same row in the next step.
  pivot_wider(id_cols = "id_code",
              names_from = "year",
              values_from = "code",
              values_fill = NULL #This will ensure that all the missing values are the same, change if appropriate.
              ) %>%
  select(-id_code) #drop the id column if no longer required.
```

I think that would be easier than using joins, but there may be better ways, someone might come along with a rowwise() solution.